# Confused about an example in my textbook (involving differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand an example in my textbook where they solve the differential equation:

$$y''(t)-4y'(t)+13y(t)=145\cos(2t)$$

Later in the example they rewrite the right side of the equation to

$$145e^{2it}$$

I know it has something to with the complex exponential function but according to the definition:

$$e^{2it}=e^{0}(\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t))\ne \cos(2t)$$

So why it legal to rewrite the right side like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $y(t)$ as the real part of a complex function $F(t)=y(t)+iz(t)$ such that 
$$F''(t)-4F'(t)+13F(t)=145e^{2it}=145(\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t)).$$
Then by taking the real part of both sides we obtain (note that the ODE is linear and with real coefficients),
$$y''(t)-4y'(t)+13y(t)=145\cos(2t).$$
On the other hand, by taking the imaginary part of both sides we have
$$z''(t)-4z'(t)+13z(t)=145\sin(2t).$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.